# Back button in Android

Tags: android

I have seen couple of Android applications when I came across one common practice. Navigation header does not have a **Back button**. Since then I was quite confused so as to place the same in the Navigation header of my application.
Should back button be placed in Navigation (Header) or we should leave keys to handle it? What is the best practice we should follow?

Thanks

Comment: Personally I dont implement and convince my clients for that as android already has support for that, earlier I faced problems but now most of the clients already aware of this

Comment: Earlier when you faced problems, which alternative you chose? Because I am in the exact situation.

Comment: i agree with Saurabh Agnihotri ... as an user of android system i like when program works in the same way ... so by pressing back button i want to back to prev screen

Comment: Look if you tell the clients to check any of the Google supplied app like gmail, youtube or any app that is in vague opera mini, facebook, they will definately take a note of that but in other situation you have no resort :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My personal view is that each platform has its own way of handling certain functions. An apple device will have a  back button on its navigation bar because that is the place where an iphone user will look for it.

As far as Android is concerned, because we are supplied with a physical back button, we must leave it at that because that is the first place an android user will look to if he wants to go back.

Therefore since user satisfaction and ease of use is the main concern, i would not play with the back button (unless i have to).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the responses above, however for the sake of simplicity I have taken a central approach in which I actually keep a back button in the navigation header however user can still press the hard key back button and the code actually performs the same functionality.

Essentially what it does is to cover both set of users, some really new ones who do not understand Android hard-keys yet, like people used to iOS (pun intended) and the other more suave Android users.

Comment: umm... if there's a pun, I don't see it. (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

oI believe there could not be best approach. It depends on your custom UI and how much screen estate your navigation consume. The best approach is to buil two variants ant alllow to beta-testers decide.
Allthow back button on the screen could be as much handy, so much annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What the "Back" button actually does, is to close your current activity and bring the previous one to the front.

You can do the same by calling finish() in your current activity. It will remove the current activity from activity Stack and take you to the previous one.

Asaf Pinhassi